# Solve $\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{4x^4-4x^2+2}=2x^3-x-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

> Could you please help me solve for $x$ in
>   $$\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{4x^4-4x^2+2}=2x^3-x-1.$$

---

I tried this way. But I could not solve further. Please help me.

$$(\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{4x^4-4x^2+2})^2=(2x^3-x-1)^2$$

Comment: The key is to eliminate the square roots 1 by 1 by putting 1 square root to 1 side and the other things to the other side; and repeating it if neccessary.

Comment: Could you please tell the exact answer , *if you know*

Comment: @RaviPrakash: You may be interested to see my answer.

Comment: @Botond: That has been tried by other people and will not yield a nice proof that can be easily done by hand. For equations that have nice solutions, we often can use inequalities to show that they are the only solutions, as in my answer. This technique works on many problems with no algebraic proof.

Answer (score 5):

As $x$ increases:

$\sqrt{4x^4-4x^2+2} = \sqrt{(2x^2-1)^2+1}$ decreases if $x \in [0,\frac12\sqrt2]$ and increases if $x \in [\frac12\sqrt2,-\infty)$.

Symmetrically $\sqrt{4x^4-4x^2+2}$ decreases if $x \in (-\infty,-\frac12\sqrt2]$ and increases if $x \in [-\frac12\sqrt2,0]$.

Therefore $\sqrt{4x^4-4x^2+2} \le \sqrt{2}$ if $|x| \le \frac12\sqrt2$.

If $x \in [0,\frac12\sqrt2]$:

$-(2x^3-x-1) = 1-x·(2x^2-1) \ge 1$.

If $x \in [-\frac12\sqrt2,0]$.

$-(2x^3-x-1) = (1-x)·(\frac12(2x+1)^2+\frac12) \ge \frac12$.

If $|x| \le \frac12\sqrt2$:

$\sqrt{4x^4-4x^2+2} \le \sqrt2 < 1+\frac12 \le 1-(2x^3-x-1)$.

If $x < -\frac12\sqrt2$:

$\sqrt{4x^4-4x^2+2} \le 2x^2 < 1-(2x^3-x-1)$ because $(x+1)·(2x^2-1) < 1$.

Therefore $\sqrt{4x^4-4x^2+2} < \sqrt{x^2+1}-(2x^3-x-1)$ if $x \le \frac12\sqrt2$.

If $x > \frac12\sqrt2$:

$\frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt{x^2+1}-(2x^3-x-1)) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} - 6x^2+1 < 0$.

Therefore $\sqrt{x^2+1}-(2x^3-x-1) = \sqrt{4x^4-4x^2+2}$ for at most one real $x$, and indeed equality holds when $x = 1$.

Comment: Nice solution, I'll try to keep this method in my mind!

Comment: starred this question just because of your beautiful answer !

Comment: @PrithiviRaj: Thanks! Nowadays, I hardly do any more inequalities, since I don't like mechanical computation, but I was pleasantly surprised to find this clean solution here. =)

Comment: @user21820 Yes, its a beautiful answer